# Is it necessary to double-check a user's password on registration?

Tags: usability

**Edit** - [migrated to ui Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2406/is-it-necessary-to-double-check-a-users-password-on-registration) (please close this question)

Do you find it necessary/worthwhile to make a user repeat his password in a registration form, assuming that form includes an email address?

Pros: I imagine there are quite a few cases where users mistype their password in the registration form.

Cons: If you require a valid email anyway, he can always retrieve/reset his password via email - and for the users that do get the password right in the first try, this is yet-another-field-in-the-registration-form (which I prefer be as simple as possible)

Comment: Con: miscreants like me who see "confirm password" and type "Shift+Tab, Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, Tab, Ctrl+V, Tab"

Answer (score 0):

I would say using the password reset functionality in place of double-entry is not *horrible*, but it would require a decent UI on the login page to ensure the "forgot your password" link is clear -- such as having it appear much bigger upon invalid password entry.

I'd personally go a different way: ask for the password after a 'verify your email address' message.

One thing to consider is you also need a valid email address -- so if they mis-enter their email, and also their password, their account is effectively locked. Many sites require clicking a link (and/or entering a code) upon account creation, in order to verify email address, before making the account active. If you're doing this, then there is an annoying UX thing to avoid: it's not always clear why my account doesn't work.

I've seen this personally where I enter a password during registration, but then it tells me "invalid password" when I try to login, rather than "your account is not yet activated". Minor, but an annoyance.

One way to get around this is to not ask for a password until they've clicked the link in the email, then you prompt to create a new password. You can use double-entry here, since it's the only thing on the form, and it's a pretty simple way to avoid an easy user mis-entry. Users are also quite used to this model, practically every password entry system works like this.

It also handles an additional use case, where the user themselves is not the one creating the account (not sure if this applies to you or not). Someone can create the account on the user's behalf, but then the user is still choosing their own password after clicking on the 'verify' link they get via email.

Answer (score 0):

I do think that it is worthwhile - as an additional validation just to ensure that users havent mistyped the password (especially coz we cannot see the password being typed in most cases). I think it provides a sense of validation to the user as well that he is in fact sure of his password before he submits the form.

However, this is valid only in case of forms which do not allow you to copy / paste from one field to the other (I have used sites where their forms allow me to copy paste which inherently makes having the 2nd field completely useless)

Personally, however, i find it extremely irritating when a form makes me re-type my password. But i still do think that its a useful validation to have.